# LDAP query to search for the active user in a particular container

Tags: ldap

I am trying to configure ldap sync in Alfresco 4.2e. I am able to authenticate the users but I am unable to sync the users.

I am using [ldapadmin browser](http://www.ldapadmin.org/index.html) to check the tree of the active directory

Here is my model ldap tree

dc: abc.def.com under that I have so many containers and organisational unit. I need the user from container named "User".

Unfortunately this User container has so many users and I am getting size exceeded limit error. Some of the users are inactive

```
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(&(objectClass\=container)(cn\=Users))
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectClass\=container)(cn\=Users))
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(objectClass\=*)
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(objectClass\=*)
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=dc\=abc,dc\=def,dc\=com
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=dc\=ter,dc\=teradyne,dc\=com
```

How to get all the users without getting size exceed limit error.

**EDIT** :

I found Under container I found few users belong to particular group named `Newly Created Users`. The group type is `security` and group scope is `Local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the results [in pages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2696) or in a [virtual list view](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/56/I-D/draft-ietf-ldapext-ldapv3-vlv-09.txt). Your ldap server must support the extension you use. A quick google search points me at this configuration option in Alfresco for paged querying:

`ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize`

Set it to something like 1000.

Comment: My querybatch size is set to 1000 only

Comment: First, try reducing the batch size (maybe half), next, verify your ldap server supports the extension and that you are connecting with LDAPv3.

Comment: Thanks that worked but the problem is I am having all the users and some of these users are disabled account. I found that the users belong to a particular group in the server named "Newly Created Users"

Comment: The disabled ones or the active ones are in "Newly Created Users"? (&(objectClass\=container)(cn\=Users)(cn\=Newly Created Users) perhaps?

Comment: Yes I am able to fetch the users. Is it possible to sync after login?

Comment: You would add that to both of your group query lines if it is a distinguishing characteristic.

Comment: Rite now I solved the problem and I am marking this answer. I will raise another question for ldap sync only for logged in users.